# how to save image into sqlite3 using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store an image into sqlite3. I am new to iOS please help me out how to save this image and retrieve in image view.

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        createDB()
        return true
    }



    func createDB()
    {
        // create db

        let dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

        let dbpath = dir.appendingPathComponent("imgdatabase.sqlite")

        print(dir)

        // check if file exist 

        let m = FileManager()

        if m.fileExists(atPath: dbpath.path)
        {

            print("file exist no need to create")
        }
        else
        {
            m.createFile(atPath: dbpath.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

        }

        // open db

        var op : OpaquePointer? = nil


        if sqlite3_open(dbpath.path, &op)==SQLITE_OK
        {

            print("db open successfuly")

            let query = "create table img_save(img text)"


            if sqlite3_exec(op, query.cString(using: .utf8), nil, nil, nil)==SQLITE_OK
            {
                print("table created ")

            }
            else
            {

                print("table  not created")
            }
        }
            else
            {
            print("db unable to open")

            }

        sqlite3_close(op)

        }
```

**Image_save_ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class Image_save_ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func img_display_click(_ sender: AnyObject) {



           }

    @IBOutlet weak var imgview: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



            }


    @IBAction func img_save_click(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "35-handgun-png-image.png")!
        let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)


        var decodeimg : NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!

        imgview.image = UIImage(data : decodeimg as Data)!


        let dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

        let dbpath = dir.appendingPathComponent("imgdatabase.sqlite")
        print(dir)
        // check if file exist

        let m = FileManager()

        if m.fileExists(atPath: dbpath.path)
        {

            print("file exist no need to create")

        }
        else
        {
            m.createFile(atPath: dbpath.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            print("db file created")


        }

        // open db

        var op : OpaquePointer? = nil

        if sqlite3_open(dbpath.path, &op)==SQLITE_OK
        {
           print("db open successfuly")

            let image_d = strBase64

            let query = String.init(format : "insert into img_save values('%@')", image_d)

            if sqlite3_exec(op, query.cString(using: .utf8), nil, nil, nil)==SQLITE_OK
            {

                print("image saved successfuly")
            }
            else
            {

                print("unable to save")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("unable to open db")
        }

        sqlite3_close(op)
    }
```

I AM ADDING HERE READDB() FUNC THAT I AM FETCHING IMAGE FROM DB

@IBOutlet weak var imgview: UIImageView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    readDB()

    //imgview.image = UIImage(named: "35-handgun-png-image.png")
        }


func readDB()

{

    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "35-handgun-png-image.png")!
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

    let docdir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    print(docdir)
    let imgurl = docdir.appendingPathComponent("35-handgun-png-image.png")

    try! imageData.write(to: imgurl)

    let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgurl.path)


    let dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    let dbpath = dir.appendingPathComponent("imgdatabase.sqlite")

    //check file if exist

    let m = FileManager()

    if m.fileExists(atPath: dbpath.path)
    {

        print("file exist no need to create")
    }
    else
    {

        m.createFile(atPath: dbpath.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print("file created")
    }

    //open db

    var opq : OpaquePointer? = nil

    if sqlite3_open(dbpath.path, &opq)==SQLITE_OK
    {

        let query = "select * from img_save"


        var st : OpaquePointer? = nil

        if sqlite3_prepare(opq, query.cString(using: .utf8), -1, &st, nil)==SQLITE_OK
        {
            while sqlite3_step(st)==SQLITE_ROW
            {

                let imgd = String.init(format : "%s",sqlite3_column_text(st, 0))
                //let imgd = String.init(format : "%s",sqlite3_value_text(st!))

                imgview.image = UIImage(named : imgd)
                print("nil value")

            }

        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(opq)

}
```

EARLIER IT WAS SHOWING FATAL ERROR FOUND NIL WHILL UNWRAPPING VALUES BUT NOW I HAVE TAKEN IMAGE VIEW TO STORE COLUM VALUE AND DISPLAY IT USING IMAGE VIEW..SO PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS I AM GETTING NIL VALUE OUT THERE

Comment: but where do you see this error?

Comment: in image_save_ view controller

Comment: where? show us what is your problem, what is nil

Comment: @Lu I am getting this error when I click on save button and I am unable to resolve this please look into it fix it or explain me with example...thank you so much in advance

Comment: OK, again, now i know that it is in `img_save_click` try to tell me more, what line?

Comment: @Lu for retrieving image I have used this code below and I am getting nil value, just look into it and fix this or explain me with example.

Comment: please help me out

Comment: @Lu I have added the code for retrieving image and getting nil value please look into it and fix it... u can see it above I have edited the code

Comment: tell me please what line crashes? you still don't show me where is the crash!

Comment: do you have "image saved successfuly" when trying to save?, did you try to look into database to see what is there after saving?

Comment: @Lu i am unalbe to open db aswell my terminal says unable to open database

Comment: When i click on save it gives me image saved successfully.. that means it is getting store but the thing is im Having prob. While retrieving  i guess

Comment: if you cant save what do you want to retreive? it is obvious you will not retreive anything if you don't save it

Comment: focus on what are you saving check this link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/167743/sqlite-swift-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If possible you write your image in application document directory by specific name.
And save that name in sqlite table. Retrieve name from sqlite and image from document directory.

Comment: @ Sanjeev Can pls explain me with example

Comment: First you write image in document directory like this
let documentsDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true) // create a name
 let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Image.jpg") if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL.path!) { if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToFile(fileURL.path!, atomically: true) { print("saved") } else { print("error ") } } else { print("file already exists") }
After save this name "Image.jpg" in sqlite table

Comment: Thnx @Saneev sir

Comment: One more question @sanjeev sir and while retrieving image what may i supposed to do pls help me out

Comment: I am not getting what are you want to say.
Just an example: if you have a screen for login and you want to show there an image. Download the image store in document directory by name "login.jpg" and also this name in a table for login screen this image name "login.jpg". When appear login screen check in table what the name of image,  if you are getting name then check image exist or not. If exist then show neither download that.
I have tried to more brief. If any concerns please let me know.